# Dump Microsoft Server Configuration server to a text file

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a way to dump every configuration from my server to a dump file like a .txt.

I see i can do it with the server propierties from the GUI, but i want it to extract it all the info wihtout going windows per windows.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you can run the following to output the installed Windows features to a text file:

```
get-windowsfeature > feature.txt
```

If you get an ObjectNotFound error, you probably need to run this first:

```
Import-Module servermanager
```

You can list off the installed Hotfixes using this command:

```
gwmi win32_quickfixengineering | sort hotfixid > hotfix.txt
```

If you're looking for specifics on the SQL Server configuration, then this question should probably have been posted to the DBA site.  There are too many possible ways to get that to list here, depending on exactly what data you want to see, but you can check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19924/how-to-compare-two-sql-server-2008-configurations for a start.